# Django DetailView don't show data in template

Tags: django, detailview

Hello I'm just starting use the CBV in Django. My ListView working normal it can get the id in models except DetailView. It don't show the detail data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17yeU-LdvV_yLjnBB2A2gYt5ymSeKvPAR/view?usp=sharing

Here the code:

models.py:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=125)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py:

```
  urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.School_List.as_view(),name='school_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.School_Detail.as_view(),name='school_detail'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class School_List(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'schoollist'
    model = School

class School_Detail(DetailView):
    contex_object_name = 'schooldetail'
    model = School
    template_name = 'basicapp/School_detail.html'
```

detail.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Site showing School Detail</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="p-5 text-white bg-dark rounded-3 container">
            <p>Name: {{schooldetail.name}}</p>
            <p>Principal: {{schooldetail.principal}}</p>
            <p>Location: {{schooldetail.location}}</p>
            <h2>Student: </h2>
            {% for student in schooldetail.students.all %}
                <p>{{student.name}} who is {{student.age}} years old</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `School_Detail` you use `Student` as `Model` instead of `School` `Model`.

Change your `Model` from `Student` to `School` as

```
class School_Detail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'schooldetail'
    model = School                       #<---- change model name here
    template_name = 'basicapp/School_detail.html'
```

Comment: Yes. I'm try both models but seem like it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `{{schooldetail.school.name}}` not `{{schooldetaill.name}}` as you using Student model in your details views so you can access School model via your foreign key fields of Student model.

```
{% block content %}
        <h1>Site showing School Detail</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="p-5 text-white bg-dark rounded-3 container">
                <p>Name: {{schooldetail.school.name}}</p>
                <p>Principal: {{schooldetail.school.principal}}</p>
                <p>Location: {{schooldetail.school.location}}</p>
                <h2>Student: </h2>
                {% for student in schooldetail.students.all %}
                    <p>{{student.name}} who is {{student.age}} years old</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I try but it not work also

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. The code is not working because in the:

```
class School_Detail(DetailView):
    contex_object_name = 'schooldetail' 
    model = School
    template_name = 'basicapp/School_detail.html'
```

I just missed a letter 't' in the `context_object_name`.